# django debug toolbar and django 1.9 escaped html in queries inspect

Tags: django, django-templates, django-debug-toolbar

I have following problem with Django `1.9.2` and `django-debug-toolbar==1.4` the SQL queries are escaped. how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an incompatibility with the [debug_panel](https://github.com/recamshak/django-debug-panel). Just had the same problem.

Edit the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings, and replace the `debug_panel.middleware.DebugPanelMiddleware` with `debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware`.